# Sequence row in SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a simple SELECT statement in need sequence number according to result (no need to group or order by)I Used Row_Number but it need Over.
any other way to do it? Please help

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS ArrayId (:here i need sequence number)
    , TRIM(CM.Category) as Category
    , TRIM(CM.SubCategory) as SubCategory
    , CM.PlantCode
    , ISNULL(PM.PlantName,'') as PlantName
    , CM.Capacity AS Capacity_
    , CM.SizeRange
    , CM.CapacityId 
FROM capacitymaster2 CM
LEFT JOIN PlantMaster2 PM ON CM.PlantCode = PM.PlantCode
WHERE CM.SubCategory IS NOT NULL AND CM.SubCategory != ''
```

Comment: Thankyou @Dale.  it means i should order .  my doubt has cleared

Comment: row_number() over (/*PARTITION BY column */order by (select  null ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` if you need a unique sequence number, but don't care about the actual order.